# Access OpenShift forwarded ports from remote host

Tags: postgresql, openshift, iptables, portforwarding

I would like to connect to a PostgreSQL (9.6) cluster that runs inside OpenShift (3.9) using port forwarding as described [here](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-connecting-database-using-port-forwarding/). To this end I set up and sanity-check port forwarding on a jump host (outside the OpenShift cluster) like this:

```
oc port-forward $pod 5432:5432
netstat -ln | grep 5432 # "tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN"
psql -U postgres -h localhost # OK
psql -U postgres -h $(hostname -i) # error: "connection refused"
```

So it looks as if port forwarding listens only for `localhost`, but not the host's other IP address(es). Ultimately I want to connect to the database thru the jump host from another remote hosts, so `localhost' won't suffice.

How can I set up (OpenShift) port forwarding in such a way that it will allow access to the forwarded port from remote hosts as well? I suppose Iptables (in combination with OpenShift port forwarding) could do the trick, but I do not yet know how and if there is a simpler approach. (The jump host runs Debian 9.5.)

**UPDATE** An approach combining an SSH tunnel and OpenShift (Kubernetes) port forwarding apparently can solve this. This was suggested in a link provided in the accepted answer below.

on jump host (1st session):

```
ssh -N -L $(hostname -i):5432:localhost:5433 $(whoami)@$(hostname)
```

on jump host (2nd session):

```
oc port-forward $pod 5433:5432
```

on remote host:

```
psql -U postgres -h jump-host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find decent discussion on port-forward listen addresses and few temporary solutions on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43962 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/46517.

Afer the PR is merged, relased in upstream kubernetes and openshift updates to that version, you will have an easy way to achieve this (I would guess minimum half a year since now). For now you're stuck with workarounds.

Comment: Good stuff: a workaround suggested in Kubernetes #43962 (using an SSH tunnel instead of Iptables) apparently solves my problem. I'll share the details in an update to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the `port-forward` allowed only local access[0], so there is not simpler way than you said. Even if the remote access can be enable, but you should configure the `iptables` for allowing `5432` port on the `node`. So if you wish to access to a `Pod` from remote, you should use the <strike>`Route` or</strike>  `Service` like communication between `Pods`.

[0] [Port Forwarding](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/port_forwarding.html)

```
You can use the CLI to forward one or more local ports to a pod. This allows you to listen on a given or random port locally, and have data forwarded to and from given ports in the pod.
```

Comment: Route can only be used for HTTP traffic, unless the protocol you want to use supports secure connections and tunnelling using TLS SNI, which PostgreSQL image used by OpenShift doesn't. You can only expose a Service direct if able to setup NodePort or LoadBalancer type Service for the cluster. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

Comment: You're right, Graham. Thank you for correcting. I'll edit the above comment related `Route`.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton FYI, I am not using OpenShift's PostgreSQL image, but an own image that is based on Debian Stretch and installs PostgreSQL 9.6.