# How to Connect using Port Forwarding Database Postgrsql on Openshift 3

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, openshift

I Have a problem on Connect from Port Forwarding Database on Openshift :

Running Pods Postgresql :
[image: Postgresql Pods have Been Running]
[image: Detail Pods Postgresql]

I Try Connect to Container running the database to check process and psql command, then it works :
[image: Connect inside container postgre]

Next, I Try Port Forwarding for Try Connection from outside Openshift Cluster:
[image: Run port forwarding postgresql]

Then I Try Connect from Outside Cluster to connect Postgresql have Error: Connection Refuse
Im Using IP Based or Hostname / FQDN Not Working and Error Still Exist
[image: Error Try Connect Postgresql to Openshift]

And When I Try Check Firewall port it has been opened port 5432/TCP :
[image: Check Ports Has Been Open or Not]

---

Anyone Can Help Me With This problem ?
Thanks

Note: Before I have Been Looking Documentation but Not Working Resolve the Problem
Source Documentation:
https://www.openshift.com/blog/openshift-connecting-database-using-port-forwarding

["psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused" Error when connecting to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439167/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-error-when-connecting-to)

Answer (score 1):

The `oc port-forward` command is forwarding from only your loopback interfaces.

If you are running your client on the same machine where the cluster is running, then use `localhost` as your "Host".

If you are running your client on a different machine, they you need more network redirection to get this to work.  Please see this post for more information as well as work-arounds for your problem:  [Access OpenShift forwarded ports from remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607821/access-openshift-forwarded-ports-from-remote-host)